# Facebook login API: avoid user hijacking

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB js SDK to allow logging in on my platform. A user permits the needed access and I save his ID in my DB. The data is sent to my server via AJAX. Since the login is with FB, I can identify the user only by his ID.

Now, lets say I know someones FB ID and I know he has an account on my platform. In runtime, I can place his ID in the auth request and obtain a legit session of that user. How could that be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, those are App Scoped IDs, it is very unlikely that someone would know the ID of a user who authorized your App, because it´s not the "real" ID.

That being said, you can (and should) send the User Token to the server and confirm the ID by calling the `/me` endpoint with that Token. You should also use `appsecret_proof` for API calls, more information can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Comment: "First of all, those are App Scoped IDs" - that's the part I'd probably missed. Thank you very much!